# Can An Android-based app be run on Samsung Gear S?

Tags: android, gears

I hava been developoing an app with gear S which I don't have.Just want to know how to develop an app using gear s

Answer (score 1):

> Can An Android-based app be run on Samsung Gear S?

No, because the Samsung Gear S does not run Android. [Its OS is a "Tizen-based wearable platform"](http://www.samsung.com/us/explore/gear-s-features-and-specs/).